# create toggle switch (android) like checkbox with only CSS without JavaScript and with single input element (no extra div or span used)

Tags: html, css, forms, user-interface, checkbox

I was creating a form and I wanted to create a checkbox but toggle switch like UI how can I make that.

Also, I wanted to make things simpler.

so, I searched everywhere and finely figured it out by myself.

There are no extra elements used and it's fully customizable in terms of size, shape, and color.
also, it is reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I made that.

```css
input[type="checkbox"].switch_1{
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 3em;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"].switch_1:checked{
    background: #0ebeff;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"].switch_1:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .25em rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            box-shadow: 0 0 .25em rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(.7);
            transform: scale(.7);
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"].switch_1:checked:after{
    left: calc(100% - 1.5em);
  }
```

```html
        <input type="checkbox" class="switch_1">
```